# Does sql server read scale AG technology allow to setup 2 AGs such that the source of both are different FCI sql servers?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019

I have got 3 sql server's (2019 enterprise edition) configured in 2-node FCIs. Each FCI is in its own WSFC.

```
FCI1 (Svr1+Svr2)
FCI2 (Svr3+Svr4)
FCI3 (Svr5+Svr6)
```

FCI1 and FCI2 has got the OLTP dbs. FCI3 has got a data warehouse that (ETL) gets the data from the FCI1 and FCI2.

I want to offload the load on the OLTP dbs from FCI1 and FCI2, and for this I want to have a near real time copy of the OLTP dbs from FCI1 and FCI2 onto FCI3, so that the ETL running on FCI3 need not query FCI1 and FCI2.

AG (read-scale) seems to be simple (cluster-less). Does this AG read-scale technology support having 2 AGs on FCI3 such that 1 AG is between FCI1 and FCI3, and the other AG is between FCI2 and FCI3?

Or do I need to create a distributed AG?

Comment: Why not just testing it ? It seems like something you could test in like 5 min...
Create a dummy DB on FCI1 and a dummy2 on FCI2 and try to create 2 AGs on FCI3 with those... you'll see if that works and you'll learn it by yourself

Comment: I wish I could do this but I have got a pentium laptop on which I am reading and learning

Comment: So FC1, FC2 and FC3 doesn't really exists ?
You could test it there... there is no risk at creating a dummy database and read-Scale AGs

Comment: They don't exist. I'm thinking through this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AG (sync vs async), AG (read scale)

The Docs don't do a great job on this and I'm open to changing them with good suggestions, however the difference between an AG and a Read Scale AG is that one uses clustering and the other doesn't. Give you're running on top of clustering already (FCI) then you can't technically create a Read Scale AG because it'll run on top of clustering (Though you can technically specify a new AG to be created with cluster type of none, this would be a poor choice for various reasons).

> Does this read scale AG technology support having 2 AGs on FCI3 such that 1 AG is between FCI1 and FCI3, and the other AG is between FCI2 and FCI3?

Yes, any AG will work for you to accomplish this, except when going across clusters which will require a distributed availability group. Again, while you could technically setup a read scale AG, it would be a poor choice for various reasons.

> Is there anything to be aware of?

Lots of stuff in the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/prereqs-restrictions-recommendations-always-on-availability?view=sql-server-ver16), if you have specific questions, ask.

Comment: Comments [archived in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141847/discussion-on-answer-by-sean-gallardy-does-sql-server-read-scale-ag-technology-a).